# Laravel Relation Parse an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, parsing, model

[image]I cant parse an multi dimensions array in correct logic?

i want to parse my array with its children: 
for example:

1. 1 parent->1child,
2. 1 parent->2 child etc
3. 2 parent 'doesnt have any child'

but in my code the else option is not working:

```
foreach ($this->categories as $s) {
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "<p style='color:red;'>".$s."</p>";
        if ($s->childrenRecursive) {
            foreach ($s->childrenRecursive as $key) {
                echo '<p>'.$s->id.''.$key->id.'</p>';
                echo "it has many children";
            }   
        } else {
            echo $s->id;
            echo "single parent without any child";
        }
    }
```

result of this code:

```
{"id":13,"image":null,"parent_id":null,"top":0,"column":1,"sort_order":0,"status":1,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-09-25 12:24:11","updated_at":"2017-09-25 12:24:11","children_recursive":[{"id":15,"image":null,"parent_id":13,"top":0,"column":1,"sort_order":0,"status":1,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-09-25 12:26:09","updated_at":"2017-09-25 12:26:09","children_recursive":[]},{"id":16,"image":null,"parent_id":13,"top":0,"column":1,"sort_order":0,"status":1,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-09-25 12:36:43","updated_at":"2017-09-25 12:36:43","children_recursive":[]}]}
```

1315

it has many children
1316

it has many children

```
[![{"id":14,"image":null,"parent_id":null,"top":0,"column":1,"sort_order":0,"status":1,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-09-25 12:25:04","updated_at":"2017-09-25 12:25:04","children_recursive":\[\]}][1]][1]
```

Comment: Try this instead `if (empty($s->childrenRecursive)) {` !!

Comment: I tried empty , isset is_null but not worked any of them.

Comment: use count() function, as count($s->childrenRecursive) > 0

Comment: Any errors? Also is `$s->childrenRecursive` a JSON string or an array?

Comment: I did a typo try it like this `if (!empty($s->childrenRecursive)) {` !!

Comment: it json but it work with count function